# Angular wire up jQuery plugins after render

Tags: angularjs, fancybox, angularjs-directive

I have created a directive, `ngAfterRender`, that I am trying to use to wire up fancybox:

Template

```
<div ng-after-render="wireUpFancyBox($event)" ng-bind-html="Content"></div>
```

Directive

```
.directive('ngAfterRender', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            $timeout(function () {
                scope.$eval(attrs.ngAfterRender, { $element: element });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Controller

```
    $scope.wireUpFancyBox = function ($element) {
        $element.find('a').fancybox($.extend(true, {}, fancyboxOptions, {
            scrolling: 'auto',
            type: 'inline'
        }));
    };
```

Unfortunately, the `wireUpFancyBox()` method is not called when the HTML `Content` binding changes.

What can I do here?

Comment: try `$timout(function(){}, 0);`

Comment: @Fourth: That made no difference.  It binds on the first render of the page, but on subsequent modifications to the `Content` value, it does not get called.

Comment: can you make a plunker with the problem? my thought is that you can bind a scope watch to attrs.ngBindHtml and then when it changes, re-eval. The problem, as I see it, is that your directive will only ever run on the first render but isn't paying attention to when the content changes and can't react to that situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `wireUpFancyBox` called every time the `ng-bind` changes then you want something like this

```
myApp.directive('ngAfterRender', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(function () {
                return scope.$eval(attrs.ngBindHtml);
            },
            function (value) { 
               $timeout(function () {   
                  scope.$eval(attrs.ngAfterRender, { $element: element });
               });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Here we put a watch on the evaluated `ng-bind-html` expression and then fire off your `eval` on a change.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmqK7/2/)

Comment: Curious- why janky?  Feels like normal (although far from obvious- thus your comment?) Angular to me

Comment: It's janky because there is no guarantee that the DOM will have rendered by the time the result of the $timeout is called.  Right?

Comment: You are guaranteed.  Here's a [good discussion on the details of why](http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/run-a-directive-after-the-dom-has-finished-rendering)